# How to include local libraries in build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a directory structure like this:

```
app/
inc/
www/
```

where `inc/` contains code that is common to *app* and *www*.  to create an image for app I do:

```
cd app
docker build .
```

so the *context* for the build are the contents of `app/`.  of course, the code in `inc/` will be missing from the app and it breaks

googling I've read suggestions that I should:

```
docker build -f app/Dockerfile .
```

which includes `inc/` (good) but also includes everything else (bad) e.g. www

to solve the problem I would have to build a script that copies the contents of `inc/` into `app/`, performs the build and the deletes `app/inc/`.  but that's messy and, actually, I can't do it because I want *docker-compose* to do my builds.

what is the recommended way to manage this?

Comment: Note: 2 years later, docker 19.03 should help with this case. See my [edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42882082/6309).

Answer (score 1):

> but also includes everything else (bad) e.g. www

That is where a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) can come in handy: declare `www/` in it.

> Before the docker CLI sends the context to the docker daemon, it looks for a file named `.dockerignore` in the root directory of the context.
>   If this file exists, the CLI modifies the context to exclude files and directories that match patterns in it.
>
> This helps to avoid unnecessarily sending large or sensitive files and directories to the daemon and potentially adding them to images using `ADD` or `COPY`.

Wrapping docker build or docker compose to generate the right `.dockerignore` would be ideal for now.

**Ultimately, each build should be able to specify its own `dockerignore` file**.
See [issue 12886](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12886).
However:

> This feature was put on hold, pending other changes that are being researched/worked on; one of those is making the builder "smarter" when sending the build context; see [#31829](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/31829).

---

Update august 2019, two years later: [issue 12886 (Add support for specifying `.dockerignore` file with `-i/--ignore`)](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12886), opened in 2015, is about to be closed with Docker 19.03:
[Tõnis Tiigi](https://github.com/tonistiigi) mentions:

> I think we can close this as the use-cases have been addressed in 19.03 and there is a lot of outdated/incorrect advice in here that may confuse new readers.
>
> This has been addressed by three features:
>
> - [#12886 (comment)](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12886#issuecomment-480575928) **allows setting a dockerignore file per Dockerfile if the repository contains many**. (Note that this was the exact description for the initial issue)
> - BuildKit automatically ignores files that are not used, automatically removing the problem where different sets of files needed to ignore each other.
> - The cases where same Dockerfile uses different sets of files for different "modes" of build (eg. dev vs prod) can be achieved with multi-stage builds and defining the mode changes with build arguments.
>
> This is not the same syntax originally requested in here because that version is incompatible with stability guarantees users expect from Dockerfiles. The provided solutions solve the problems for the users who need better control for ignored files, without adding new ones to the others.

So:

> " load `<dockerfile-name>.dockerignore` first and then fall back to `.dockerignore` if it can't be found" has landed in the test distribution of Docker (19.03.0-beta1)
>
> You need to enable BuildKit mode to use it, example:

```
$ export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1

$ echo "FROM ubuntu \n COPY . tmp/" > Dockerfile
$ cp Dockerfile Dockerfile2
$ touch foo bar
$ echo "foo" > .dockerignore
$ echo "bar" > Dockerfile2.dockerignore

$ docker build -t container1 -f Dockerfile .
$ docker build -t container2 -f Dockerfile2 .

$ docker run container1 ls tmp
Dockerfile
Dockerfile2
Dockerfile2.dockerignore
bar
$ docker run container2 ls tmp
Dockerfile
Dockerfile2
Dockerfile2.dockerignore
foo
```

Comment: if I do that I can't build `www/`

Comment: @ekkis why not? if you go in `www` and `docker build` there, the `.dockerignore` file create in the *parent* folder of `www` won't matter.

Comment: but what you're suggesting is that the context of the build (the parent directory) is where you would place the `.dockerignore`.  since I put `www/` in the file, the build copies everything *but* www, which is fine when building *app* but bad when building *www* (since that would need to be built from the parent directory as well)

Comment: @ekkis then you need to wrap your `docker build` command in a script which would generate the right `.dockerignore` file, depending on what you want to build (`app` or `www`)

Comment: but as I mentioned, I can't script stuff because ultimately my builds will be done by *docker-compose*

Comment: @ekkis Then this does not seem to be supported yet... see the links/issues I have found and added to the answer as reference.