# Ignoring subfolders not working

Tags: docker

I'm using a `.dockerignore` file that looks like this:

```
*
*/node_modules
*/bower_components
!www
!app
!inc
```

so here what I'm saying is: ignore all files in the current directory (this post is related to: [How to include local libraries in build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882069/how-to-include-local-libraries-in-build)) except for `www`, `app` and `inc` *and* ignore all directories named `node_modules` and `bower_components` in those subdirectories

when I run a build:

```
build --no-cache -t test -f app/Dockerfile .
```

(here's my Dockerfile):

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app/
```

and then run a container:

```
run -i --entrypoint=/bin/bash test
```

if I look in the directory I see node_modules folders!

```
# ls -alF
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Mar 19 03:39 ./
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Mar 19 03:39 ../
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Mar 18 03:26 inc/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 19 00:57 app/
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Mar 18 08:55 www/

# ls -alF app
total 36
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Mar 19 00:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4096 Mar 19 03:39 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   38 Mar 19 00:57 .dockerignore
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  359 Mar 19 03:37 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  700 Mar 18 04:50 config.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 3786 Mar 18 03:43 index.js
drwxr-xr-x 119 root root 4096 Mar 17 18:57 node_modules/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2910 Mar 17 20:51 npm-debug.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  348 Mar 19 03:24 package.json
```

so the first line of the `.dockerignore` worked fine, as did the 4th, 5th and 6th lines, but the subdirectories failed. for the sake of completeness I originally used `**/node_modules` but that failed too.

what is the correct way of expressing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, apparently the problem is that when I create exceptions to the ignore rules, I have to reapply the exceptions, so if I do this instead:

```
*
!www
!app
!inc
*/node_modules
*/bower_components
```

it works because `*/node_modules` applies to "all of the above", which includes `app`.  in my original declaration I was excluding the directories I do want to include from the rules

Comment: That's correct, .dockerignore files are order sensitive, the last matching line to include or exclude is what applies.