# Specify dockerignore from command line

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a .dockerignore file, but for one use case, I want to specify the contents of .dockerignore at the command line, something like:

```
docker build --ignore="node_modules" -t foo .
```

is there a way to do this from the command line? I am not seeing this in the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--

Comment: I created an issue for Docker/Moby - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37159

Answer (score 17, accepted):

2018: No, [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) does not offer an alternative to the [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file).

That is why I usually keep a symbolic link `.dockerignore` pointing to the actual `.dockerignore_official`, except for certain case, where I switch the symlink to `.dockerignore_module`.

This is a workaround, but that allows me to version the different version of dockerignore I might need, and choose between the two.

---

Update April 2019: as mentioned by [Alba Mendez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710951/alba-mendez) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547489/specify-dockerignore-from-command-line/50547987?noredirect=1#comment97616808_50547987), [PR 901](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/901) should help:

> ### dockerfile: add dockerignore override support
>
> Frontend will first check for `<path/to/Dockerfile>.dockerignore` and, if it is found, it will be used instead of the root `.dockerignore`.

See [`moby/buildkit` commit b9db1d2](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/commit/b9db1d242bf48bfc9e1fabf3f288b7354f8f23be).

It is in [Docker v19.03.0 beta1](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases/tag/v19.03.0-beta1), and **Alba** has posted an [example here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12886#issuecomment-480575928):

> You need to enable Buildkit mode to use:
>
> ```
> $ export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
>
> $ echo "FROM ubuntu \n COPY . tmp/" > Dockerfile
> $ cp Dockerfile Dockerfile2
> $ touch foo bar
> $ echo "foo" > .dockerignore
> $ echo "bar" > Dockerfile2.dockerignore
>
> $ docker build -t container1 -f Dockerfile .
> $ docker build -t container2 -f Dockerfile2 .
> $ docker run container1 ls tmp
> Dockerfile
> Dockerfile2
> Dockerfile2.dockerignore
> bar
>
> $ docker run container2 ls tmp
> Dockerfile
> Dockerfile2
> Dockerfile2.dockerignore
> foo
> ```

Update August 2019: this is now in Docker 19.03, with the following comment from [Tõnis Tiigi](https://github.com/tonistiigi):

> - [#12886 (comment)](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12886#issuecomment-480575928) allows setting a dockerignore file per Dockerfile if the repository contains many. (Note that this was the exact description for the initial issue)
> - BuildKit automatically ignores files that are not used, automatically removing the problem where different sets of files needed to ignore each other.
> - The cases where same Dockerfile uses different sets of files for different "modes" of build (eg. dev vs prod) can be achieved with multi-stage builds and defining the mode changes with build arguments.

---

Note: [issue 37129 "add support for multiple (named) build-contexts"](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37129#event-9378741979) reports in May 2023 it is now supported with:

- [`docker build (23+)`/`docker buildx build`](https://www.docker.com/blog/dockerfiles-now-support-multiple-build-contexts/)
- [Compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9461)
- [docker buildx bake](https://docs.docker.com/build/bake/build-contexts/)

See also "[Build docker image using different directory contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084798/6309)"

Comment: @AlexanderMills Well done. I have subscribed to it (as well as 12886 and 37129)

Comment: A pull request was just merged into BuildKit https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/901, hopefully it'll land on Docker soon.

Comment: @AlbaMendez Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Update: The feature just landed in [Docker 19.03.0-beta1](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases/tag/v19.03.0-beta1) and is available in the test channels. You need to enable Buildkit mode to use it, I've posted an example of use [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12886#issuecomment-480575928).

Comment: @AlbaMendez Thank you for the update: I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Update: The feature has now landed on stable Docker (19.03). The issue has been closed, a maintainer left [this comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12886#issuecomment-518843764) as an overview.

Comment: @AlbaMendez Thank you. Updated. I realize I already  included that comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42882082/6309.

Comment: @AlbaMendez thank you! This just saved me a ton of debugging time

Comment: @AlbaMendez May 2023: 37129 is completed, see the end of this answer.